# FaceDetector was not released with FaceDetector.release()

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working with ML face detector: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android#kotlin_2

And I take an image from Camera2 and process it. But I constantly have the error "FaceDetector was not released with FaceDetector.release()"

More details:

```
W/FaceDetector: FaceDetector was not released with FaceDetector.release()
E/BufferQueueProducer: [ImageReader-960x1280f23m2-7166-0](id:1bfe00000000,api:4,p:386,c:7166) dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
```

I had followed this tutorial in order to get the camera2: https://medium.com/@tylerwalker/integrating-camera2-api-on-android-feat-kotlin-4a4e65dc593f

Here is the code I tried to do for ML:

```
val realTimeOps = FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
.setContourMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CONTOUR_MODE_ALL)
.build()
val detector = FaceDetection.getClient(realTimeOps)
imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({
    imageReader.acquireLatestImage()?.let { image ->
    val mlImage = InputImage.fromMediaImage(image, 0) // TODO change image for calculation


    val result = detector.process(mlImage)
        .addOnSuccessListener {faces ->
            Log.d("photo", "Face found!")
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            Log.d("photo", "Error: $e")
        }

        image.close()
    }
}, Handler { true })
```

And also, my "detector" val has no function release :'(

I hope that someone can help me with that :)

Comment: Read the descriptions of tags before using them.

Comment: Sorry, it was my first post, will be careful next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out how did this error happen!

There must be only one instance of the detector. And the error was in another part of my code (I am new to android and first time working with camera2):

```
 cameraCharacteristics[CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP]?.let { streamConfigurationMap ->
                streamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)
                    ?.let { yuvSizes ->
                        val previewSize = yuvSizes.last()
                        val displayRotation = windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation
                        val swappedDimensions = areDimensionsSwapped(displayRotation, cameraCharacteristics)
                        val rotatedPreviewWidth = if (swappedDimensions) previewSize.height else previewSize.width
                        val rotatedPreviewHeight = if (swappedDimensions) previewSize.width else previewSize.height
                        surfaceView.holder.setFixedSize(rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight)

                        
                        val imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight,
                            ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2)

                        val realTimeOps = FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                            .setContourMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CONTOUR_MODE_ALL)
                            .build()
                        val detector: FaceDetector = FaceDetection.getClient(realTimeOps)
                        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({
                            imageReader.acquireLatestImage()?.let { image ->

                                val mlImage = InputImage.fromMediaImage(image, getRotationCompensation(cameraDevice.id, getInstance(), true))


                                val result = detector.process(mlImage)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener {faces ->
                                        if (faces.size > 0)
                                            Log.d("photo", "Face found!")
                                        else
                                            Log.d("photo", "No face have been found")
                                    }
                                    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                                        Log.d("photo", "Error: $e")
                                    }
                                    .addOnCompleteListener {
                                        image.close()
                                    }
                            }
                        }, Handler { true })


                        val previewSurface = surfaceView.holder.surface
                        val recordingSurface = imageReader.surface

                        val captureCallback = object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                            override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {

                            }

                            override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {

                                val previewRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(
                                    TEMPLATE_PREVIEW
                                ).apply {
                                    addTarget(previewSurface)
                                    addTarget(recordingSurface)
                                }

                                session.setRepeatingRequest(
                                    previewRequestBuilder.build(),
                                    object: CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {},
                                    Handler { true }
                                )
                            }
                        }

                        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(mutableListOf(previewSurface, recordingSurface), captureCallback, Handler {true})
                    }
```

I put the creation of the FaceDetector inside of the cameraCharacteristics, but this function was called everytime an image was captured. I needed to put the creation of the FaceDector outside of this one (so obviously since he want only one instance, google is yelling at me).

Now I got it at the begining of the listener "onOpened" of the CameraDevice.StateCallback().

I think the best would be to put the detector at null as a private attribute of the class, then load it in the listener of onOpened() and close it at the listener of onDisconnected().